# How to read this json with gson?

Tags: java, json, spring, gson

I have this Json and I don't know how to read when the atributtes are dynamic...

Note that example below, the field "atletas" is a List by "Ids"... How can I get this information if I don't know what Id will get?

For example:

```
{

  "rodada": 2,
  "atletas":  
    "100651": {
      "apelido": "Rodrygo",
      "pontuacao": 1.3,
      "scout": {
        "FC": 3,
        "FF": 1,
        "FS": 1,
        "RB": 1
      },
      "foto": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/2017/11/01/b8128d3d5db5325dc238cadc67c28342_FORMATO.png",
      "posicao_id": 5,
      "clube_id": 277
    },
    "101957": {
      "apelido": "Thiago Larghi",
      "pontuacao": 0,
      "scout": {

      },
      "foto": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/2018/03/19/b1b3b42713071408fb76d25cfb76d927_FORMATO.jpeg",
      "posicao_id": 6,
      "clube_id": 282
    },
    "36773": {
      "apelido": "Julio Cesar",
      "pontuacao": 8,
      "scout": {
        "DD": 1,
        "SG": 1
      },
      "foto": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/2018/04/17/326a0f6b72076eb12b4e6b335ae6a1da_FORMATO.png",
      "posicao_id": 1,
      "clube_id": 262
    }
......
```

'

Comment: Your JSON appears to be malformed. Are you missing a square bracket `"atletas": [`?

Comment: And it seems like a field `Map<String,Atleta> atletas` would work.

Comment: @chrylis it’s work! Thank you so much!!!!!